# How do I get a year (yyyy) from a mm/dd/yyyy in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column formatted as mm/dd/yy and I need to build a column that gives me yyyy.

Thanks!

Comment: `=YEAR(mm/dd/yyyy)` or `=TEXT(mm/dd/yyyy,"YYYY")`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+how+do+I+get+the+year+from+a+date&oq=excel+how+do+I+get+the+year+from+a+date shows *plenty* of valid links you could have tried first

Answer (score 0):

Searched a little differently and found the answer.

Use the YEAR function, with the variable being the cell that currently has the mm/dd/yy date.

Answer (score 0):

If **A1** contains the full date, then in another cell use:

```
 =Year(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in A1, and you know the format will always be correct, with a 4 digit year on the far right:

`=RIGHT(A1, 4)`

You can also create a custom date format that only shows the year.  Highlight your column, click the drop down for number formats and select Custom.

[image]

Enter a custom format here and click OK.  For your case, use "yyyy".

[image]